# I was stuck by a combinatoric question. Can someone give me a hint?

Tags: combinatorics

In the game "Don't Fall Off The Cliff," you may move forward any positive number of steps, not move, or move one step backward. Each of these three options takes one turn. How many ways can you finish and come back to the point where you started after  turns, while never going behind where you started? It looks like a Catalan Number. But l am only familiar with the two-dimensional one. This problem should be 3-dimensional. X refers to go forward any positive number of steps, y refers to stay there, z refers to move one step backward